# Is there a word that describes seeing and hearing as one thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that is the synthesis of seeing and hearing together.

Answer (score 7):

***audiovisual***

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/audiovisual

> of, pertaining to, involving, or directed at both hearing and sight

Comment: I love the simplicity of your answer -sometimes, definitions are just that

Comment: _seeing_ and _hearing_ are verbs. _audiovisual_ is not. It is not easy to use it in the same way.

Comment: A verb would be not a single word anymore. Something like "perceiving audiovisually"

Comment: This also depends on how the OP intend to use it of course. Sometimes we need more context to be able to find the right expression.

Comment: @awe _seeing_ and _hearing_ are also nouns, and the title asks for _one thing_ rather than _one action_.

Comment: @Neil: Yes. I see it now.

Comment: The question is asking for a single word for the combination of 2 sorts of perception. I'd be surprised if you could do that in a single English word, the best you could get is probably "audiovisual perception".